# checking both scrollTop and id offset in single condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check the scroll position is greater than 350 and menuSticky offset position is  92 in same condition.that condition is not working.I gave my piece of code

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
if(($(document).scrollTop() >= 350) && (($('.menuSticky').offset().top )==92)) {
           console.log('true');
           $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
          $('.secMenu').hide();
             $(this).toggleClass("open");
        }).mouseleave(function(){
          $('.secMenu').show();
        });    
       }
      });
```

Comment: the condition will match if the menusticky is at 92 pixel from the top and scroll top is equal or more than 350. Could you show your html to check if it will ever meet these 2 conditions

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing $(document).scrollTop() with $(window).scrollTop()

```js
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   if (($(window).scrollTop() >= 350) && (($('.menuSticky').offset().top) == 92)) {
     console.log('true');
     $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
       $('.secMenu').hide();
       $(this).toggleClass("open");
     }).mouseleave(function() {
       $('.secMenu').show();
     });
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working without any problems, in the following snippet I am using your code without any edits but I gave the `.menuSticky` `margin-top:92px;` so your second condition will be true and It works fine .

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if(($(document).scrollTop() >= 350) && (($('.menuSticky').offset().top )==92)) {
    console.log('true');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menuSticky" style="margin-top:92px"> Menu </div>
<div style="height:1000px;">Some content</div>
```

Comment: I have append the menuStick when the scroll position is 350 and done this code.I not sure for that It is not working for me